# PHP SOAP Request includes multiple identical tags

Tags: php, soap

OK, so I have this external SOAP based webservice, and PHP SoapClient. Everything is fine with basic requests, but I need to create a parameter set that looks like this:

```
<DatasetList>
  <DatasetID>K0001</DatasetID>
  <DatasetID>K0002</DatasetID>
</DatasetList>
```

For a single nested DatasetID tag I'd do:

```
$req = array( "DatasetList" => array( "DatasetId" => "K0001" ));
$client->getWebserviceCall($req);
```

but I need multiple DatasetID tags... I've tried assigning DatasetID as an array, but I just get:

```
<DatasetList>
  <DatasetID>Array</DatasetID>
</DatasetList>
```

Anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the array this way?

$req = array( "DatasetList" => array("DatasetID" => array("K0001", "K0002));

Comment: Yes, I just get <DatasetID>Array</DatasetID> out (literally)

Comment: are you sure you had "DatasetID" correctly with the right case - i.e., in your post you have it with a lowercase 'i'.

Comment: I meant lowercase 'd' - "DatasetId" => "K0001"

Comment: Alas my case was correct... I just triple checked. The above is pseudo code, the real stuff is more complex

Comment: can you provide a bit more code? When you try it with just K0001 does it work?

Comment: Yes, it works fine with array("DatasetID" => "K0001") but not array(DatasetID => array("K0001"))

Answer (score 2):

You can do this only by wrote the Part with the identical tags by hand. But, the rest of values can you define in a array:

```
// Define multiple identical Tags for a part of the Array
$soap_var= new SoapVar('
  <DatasetID>1</DatasetID>
  <DatasetID>2</DatasetID>
';

// Define the other Values in the normal Way as an array
$req = array( 
  "DatasetList" => $soap_var,
  'value2'=>array('other'=>'values'
);
```